# Can an abstract class extend JdbcDaoSupport/NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to implement a Spring MVC web-app (using Spring-FW-ver: 4.3.1). And my web-app's DAO layer architecture is as follows :-

```
//1. BaseDAO interface
public interface BaseDAO {
    //abstract methods
}

//2. BaseDAOJdbcImpl.java file - an abstract DAO class for common method(s) which other sub-DAO classes can inherit
@Repository
public abstract class BaseDAOJdbcImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements BaseDAO 
{
    // implementations of above BaseDAO abstract methods        
}

//3. UserDAO interface that extends BaseDAO interface
public interface UserDAO extends BaseDAO {
    //abstract methods for User
}

//4. UserDAOJdbcImpl.java class file
@Repository
public class UserDAOJdbcImpl extends BaseDAOJdbcImpl implements UserDAO 
{
    // implementations of above UserDAO abstract methods
}
```

And the `webapp-servlet.xml` Spring-MVC config file :-

```
.
.
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="springcrud"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/pmsDS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="baseDAOJdbcImpl" class="springcrud.dao.BaseDAOJdbcImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
.
.
```

I'm getting the following error :-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
```

The `dataSource` object is not being injected into DAO layer. Is the above DAO layer architecture valid or is it a problem with Spring configuration?